# How can I use VLOOKUP with conditional formatting based on specific text in a table?

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

So I have all the depth charts for all of the NFL teams in a single sheet, in one big table, and then I have the current week's injury report in a second sheet. On that second sheet, it lists the player's name in one column and their status (questionable, doubtful, out, or injury reserve) in another. From this I used nested if statements to replace the statuses with numbers 1-4.

What I'm looking to do is assign different colors to the depth charts on sheet one based on the players' statuses on the injury report (yellow for questionable, red for IR, etc.). So essentially I want to vlookup each value in the table and assign the appropriate color according to their status in the injury report.

I tried using a new rule in conditional formatting and using the formula "VLOOKUP(B3, Injuries!$A$1:$C$261,3)=1" to format for the first status, but it didn't do anything. The main pitfall is that I don't know how to reference all of the cells in the depth chart indivually for vlookup.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It works for me when I put the value to find in B3 and conditional format it to change colour with this formula `VLOOKUP(B3, Injuries!$A$1:$C$261,3)=1` and an appropriate row on Injuries exists where Ax is the lookup value and Cx is the value 1.  Can you explain what you did in a bit more detail so we can see where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quote in your formula so its look like this

```
=VLOOKUP(B3, Injuries!$A$1:$C$261,3)=1
```